# Spy object value not changed with when, thenReturn

Tags: java, mockito

```
public class MainClass {
    public void method1() {
        …….
        String str = getMethod2();
        method3(str);
    }

    protected String getMethod2() {
        String str = “Actual Value”
        return str;
    }
    private void method3(String strparam) {
        …… 
    }
}

@RunWith(MockitoJunitRunner.class)
public class Testclass {
     @InjectMocks
     MainClass obj = new MainClass();

 ……
     @Test
    public void testSpy() {
        MainClass spyMain =  spy(obj);
        when(spyMain.getMethod2()).thenReturn(new String("Testing spy"));

        obj.method1(); 
        ……..
     }
}
```

Want to use a new value returned from getMethod2() from test as it’ll be passed to method3.
I was under the impression that the call to method1 from test class calls  method2 and I thought the value retuned from method2 is  “Testing spy” but is “Actual Value” and the “Actual Value” is passed to method3 when test class is ran.
How to use the new value from test class?

Comment: Your code doesn't even compile? `Syntax error on token "Public", public expected` - and so on ;)

Comment: As @maio290  mentioned.  The example is not java code.

Answer (score 1):

You are calling the method on `obj` (`obj.method1();`), instead of on the object that you've spied: `spyMain.method1();`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the code in your example is actually java code and the capitalization was added when you copied it into Microsoft Word (or some other word processor),
try this:

```
public void testSpy()
{
    MainClass spyMain = spy(obj);
    doReturn("Blammy").when(spyMain).getMethod2();

    obj.method1(); 
}
```

Here are some more info:

- The test class must be in the same package as the MainClass.
  For example:
  Location of MainClass: src/main/java/blammy/MainClass.java
  Location of TestClass: src/test/java/blammy/TestClass.java
- The `doReturn` variation of mocking does not call the wrapped method,
  but the `thenReturn` variation does.
- This is wrong:
  `@InjectMocks`
  `MainClass obj = new MainClass();`
  Only use the `@InjectMocks` annotation if you are calling `MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(class)`.

Here is your test class rewritten to use `@InjectMocks`

```
@RunWith(MockitoJunitRunner.class)
public class Testclass
{
    @InjectMocks
    private MainClass classToTest;

    @Before
    public void beforeTest()
    {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this)
    }

    @Test
    public void testSpy()
    {
        spyClassToTest = spy(classToTest);
        doReturn("Testing spy").when(spyClassToTest ).getMethod2();

        spyClassToTest.method1(); 
    }
}
```

More Notes:
You may be able to use `@Spy` and `@InjectMocks` on the same object
(in my example, on classToTest),
but I never do that.

Comment: Thank you, for your responces. I'll try these. I am new to mockito.